# CPU Temperature suddenly to high

Tags: cpu, fan, temperature, cpu-temperature

After I came back from holiday (computer was off for a few days). I startet my computer and run into this error message during boot:

Photo of the error message during boot:

[image: Photo of the error message during boot]

Photo of BIOS information:

[image: Photo of BIOS information] The voltage does not seem to be to high and the cooler connected to it runs with 1011RPM (which sounds a louder than usual).

First I reset all BIOS configurations - didn't help. Then I cleaned everything I could, pulled out the BIOS battery and detached and attached the CPU_FAN cable again — didn't help.

I don't have any Idea what else could be wrong?
The computer runs a few minutes in BIOS and then turns off (I guess because of the temperature) Booting into windows is possible but the computer turns off when I reach the desktop. The BIOS is flashed to the most recent version.

CPU center, attached cooler is left:

[image: CPU center, attached cooler is left]

CPU Fan cable is attached where the CPU_OPT arrow is pointing to:

[image: CPU Fan cable is attached where the CPU_OPT arrow is pointing to]

I did not change any hardware, so I guess the cables should be at the right pins.

Anyone any idea what else I could check?

Comment: Was the computer connected to the mains during the holidays, or is it protected by a UPS?

Comment: Can you try connecting the pump to the CPU_FAN header? If it's occupied, try switching around the cables. If it doesn't work, your cooler is probably dead.

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 There is no pump? I just have the box fan. The fan is working, it spinns with 1011RPM. Or do I missunderstand you somehow?

Comment: @harrymc The computer where plugged out completly

Comment: Sorry it looks like from your screenshot that you're using a watercooling setup.

Comment: Can you still try plugging the fan to the CPU_FAN header?

Comment: Hehe no problem, it looks like this from a little more distance https://imgur.com/a/qwJGOyX

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 I don't have a CPU_FAN header ... I just have 8 W_PUMP pins and 4 CPU_OPT pins (3 are used).  Photo: https://imgur.com/a/DvjLIAX

Comment: Can you try moving some fans around in the CPU_OPT headers and seeing what works?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 I just consulted the Manual it looks like right now I pluged in the fan into CPU_FAN. But I can try CPU_OPT also. https://imgur.com/a/ZyFJuua

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 Just tried the CPU_OPT, it didn't change anything. Still the same problem

Comment: @rockZ - It is clear from your screenshot your using an AIO water cooler, which has failed, due to high temperatures you are running at.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks you lead to on the right way. I figured it out and solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it,
Thanks to @Ramhound

For any reason the "Water Pump Control" was set do disabled.
Setting it to DC Mode solved the issue.

[Set waterpump to DC Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjNlT.jpg)

I still don't know how or when the pump changed into disabled mode but I figured out that, even if you run the fan configuration wizard in bios the system does never set the waterpump mode into an active state. You have to do it manually.

Comment: If you updated the firmware it might have happened then